# Script command to trigger upon exiting program called by same bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a script that opens a program that can remain open for an indeterminate amount of time. What I would like to do, is have a cleanup command called upon exiting this program. It's a separate command that we're having our techs issue manually when they exit the program, however, they aren't always diligent.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Essentially they'd CTRL+C out or using the "X" button in the GUI. The terminal in which it was called (or my script ran) remains open. So far I haven't found anything that allows me to block on while a program is running when opened by that script.

Thanks!

Comment: More details needed. By default, bash commands are run sequentially, i.e. each subsequent command is waiting for the previous one to finish. I would expect the answer to be just `runMyProgram.sh && doCleanup.sh`

Is the `runMyProgram.sh` being executed in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `trap` command, which supports a fake signal called `EXIT`:

```
trap 'exitScript.sh' EXIT
```

This will execute `exitScript.sh` regardless of the reason for exit, including CTRL+C but not including a KILL (9) signal.